# "int" object is not iterable error? How to fix?

Tags: python

For my CIS 104 class we are learning python and one of the professors examples is:

```py
total=sum(10, 20) 
print(total)

total=sum(5, sum(10, 20))
print(total)
```

When I attempt the first line of code, total=sum(10, 20), I get an "int" object is not iterable error. Ive tried several options but can't seem to figure out why its not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"The sum() function adds the items of an iterable and returns the sum"_. It should take for example an array of value to sum as an argument. Try that code : `sum([10, 20])`. You called sum() with two different parameters that are integers, and as it says are not iterable values. Instead you have to pass 1 argument which is an Iterable of values to sum.

Comment: that doesn't look like a very good professor, or at least one that isn't very familiar with python, to add two number together you do with the plus sign `10+20`, `sum` is too a list of numbers together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum` doesn't work like that. It takes an argument of an iterable (a `List`) and, if two arguments are provided, a starting value.

So what you need to do is to add your items to a List

`numbers = [10, 20]`

and then feed this list to the `sum` function

```
total = sum(numbers)
print(total)
```

This is gonna print `30`. When you provide a `start` parameter

```
total = sum(numbers, 5)
```

You'll get `35` instead.

Answer (score 0):

in `help(sum): sum(iterable, start=0, /)`

if you want to sum it, do `sum((10, 20))` or `10 + 20`.

(how to iterable check:
`iter(object)` -> ERROR! -> object is not iterable)

Answer (score 0):

You can always look at the official documentation such as [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

Therefore, please use `sum([10, 20])`

```
>> sum([10, 20])
30
>> sum([5, 10, 20])
35
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sum()` method takes an iterable (e.g. list, dict, tuple etc.) as argument.
So if you update your code like this it should work.

```
total=sum([10, 20])
print(total)
# 30
total=sum([5, 10, 20])
# 35
print(total)
```